# Why does windows take much time for login window to reappear when password is wrong?

Tags: authentication, windows-7, windows-7-x64

It is a general problem with windows7. When i try to login and password is right, it will login instantaneously, but when the password is wrong, it takes more then 10 sec for login window to reappear.

Microsoft does not share its code, so it becomes difficult to guess, but i believe i can get a descent answer from stackoverflow community.

Comment: Same situation on all Linux system i tried, maybe you can tag Linux as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting observations.

I can only guess it's the old thing of:  one way to frustrate an attacker is to slow them up when they answer wrong.  I use this idea in some of my code.  Just call sleep for awhile.

Comment: I love this explanation! Same situation on all Linux system i tried and I am so puzzled, I planned to ask question here until i saw your this. Will it be the same reason for Linux?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure *nix systems use this too.